# While vs. Repeat Loops in R?

Tags: r

I was wondering what the difference is between a "while" loop versus a "repeat" loop in R, apart from the syntax. Are there specific cases that I should keep an eye out for in deciding which one to use? (For example, is the difference similar to using "for" loops for functions versus the apply loops?)

From my reading of the documentation, I would prefer a while loop since the break condition is right next to the "while" command, though I guess the "repeat" loop seems a little more flexible.

Best,
Ben

Answer (score 17):

The syntax for the commands can be seen in `?Control`:

```
while(cond) expr
repeat expr
```

This makes it clear that `while` tests a condition to determine when to finish looping, but `repeat` requires you to explicitly `break` the loop on your own and can be at any point in the body of the loop. Depending on where you place your `break` statement, `repeat` may perform further parts of an iteration compared to `while`.

Consider these 2 forms of the same loop:

```
i <- 0
repeat {
  if (i == 2)
    break
  print(i)
  i <- i + 1
}
# [1] 0
# [1] 1
i
# [1] 2

i <- 0
while (i != 2) {
  print(i)
  i <- i + 1
}
# [1] 0
# [1] 1
i
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 7):

In a context not specific to `R`, `repeat` loop checks the condition at the end of each iteration while `while` loop checks it at the beginning of each iteration. So `repeat` loop executes at least one iteration while `while` loop may not execute any iterations if the condition is not fulfilled. That's the difference.

Comment: And actually needing them is a rare exception in R.

Comment: This is not necessarily true in R. `repeat` is exited "manually" and can be at any point in the body of the loop - even prior to any substantial processing taking place.

Comment: Also, there is no explicit condition check at the end. `repeat` must be exited manually.

Comment: Not too sure why this answer has so many upvotes. It fails to identify the difference between the `while` and `repeat` loop at the high level(implementation level). The comments did pick up some of the loose ends, but the answer provided by @James below is much more clear.

Comment: Just so maybe it clicks in someone else's mind too, it seems to be much like the difference between a while(){} and a do{}while() loop; where it's basically just would you rather conditionally enter or exit the loop?

Answer (score 2):

**Repeat loop**
The Repeat loop executes the same code again and again until a stop condition is met.
It means that in repeat loop the stop condition is present inside the loop.
For Example:

```
   v <- c("Hello","loop")
cnt <- 2

repeat {
   print(v)
   cnt <- cnt+1

   if(cnt > 5) {
      break
   }
}
```

The output is

```
  [1] "Hello" "loop" 
[1] "Hello" "loop" 
[1] "Hello" "loop" 
[1] "Hello" "loop"
```

In the above example the stop condition i.e; `if(cnt > 5){break}` is present inside the repeat loop itself.

**While loop**
The While loop executes the same code again and again until a stop condition is met.
For example:

```
   v <- c("Hello","while loop")
cnt <- 2

while (cnt < 7) {
   print(v)
   cnt = cnt + 1
}
```

The output is

```
 [1] "Hello"  "while loop"
[1] "Hello"  "while loop"
[1] "Hello"  "while loop"
[1] "Hello"  "while loop"
[1] "Hello"  "while loop
```

In the **while loop**, if condition is met, then it enters the loop and execute the code.
But in the **repeat loop** ,it repeatedly executes the code inside the block until the stop condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has all the answers. I like to use `while` when I have just one condition and want to see it upfront. On the other hand, I find `repeat` more flexible when it comes to multiple conditions to be met along the code. Also, with `repeat` you can put the interruption right there when the condition no longer applies.  In the example below, I put two conditions. The execution will stop either when `i` reaches 5 or when a random number between 1 and 10 multiplied by `i` is bigger than 20.

```
i <- 0 


repeat{

if(i == 5) break

print("first text")

i <- i + 1

j <- sample(1:10,1)*i

if (j > 20) break

print("second text")

}
```